# jquery to check Email availability/duplication in database

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am trying to check Email availability on text change event of a textbox. Below is the code (I picked up from the net):

HTML (javascript):

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#<%=txtEmailAddress.UniqueID%>").change(function () {

            var uname = $("#<%=txtEmailAddress.UniqueID%>");

            var msgbox = $("#status");

            if (Email.val().length > 0) {

                $.ajax({

                    type: "POST",

                    url: "SignUp.aspx/usp_CheckEmail",

                    data: "{'args': '" + Email.val() + "'}",

                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",

                    dataType: "json",

                    success: function (msg) {

                        if (msg.d == 'Available') {

                            Email.removeClass("notavailablecss");

                            Email.addClass("availablecss");

                            msgbox.html('<img src="Images/a.png"> <font color="Green"> Available </font>');

                        }
                        else {
                            Email.removeClass("availablecss");

                            Email.addClass("notavailablecss");

                            msgbox.html(msg.d);

                        }
                    }
                });
            }
            else {

                Email.addClass("notavailablecss");

                msgbox.html('<font color="#cc0000">Email must be unique</font>');

            }

        });

    });
```

CS:

```
 [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]

protected void txtPassword_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e, string args)
    {
 string returnValue = string.Empty;

 SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConnectionString"]);


try
{

SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("usp_CheckEmail", con);

sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", args.Trim());

con.Open();

int success = int.Parse((sqlCmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString()));

if(success == 1) // Email Not Available
{
returnValue = "<img src="Images1/n.png"><font color="#cc0000"><b>'" + args + "'</b> is    already in use.</font>";   **//getting syntax error here**

  }
  else if(success == 0)//Email is available
{
 returnValue = "Available";
 }

}
 catch
 {
 //Handle Error
 }
 finally
 {
 con.Close();
 }

return returnValue;
 }

    }
 }
```

Getting an error in the return value line. What would be the correct syntax?? Also, it is supposed to display images like this:[image: na]

So, do I need to have image controls on my .aspx page? Because the article that I got this code from, did not mention to have image controls. And if yes, how do I bind them with the code then??

UPDATE: heres the link to where I got  the code from
http://www.dotnetspark.com/kb/Content.aspx?id=1278

What all things are missing from the article?? what else needs to be done? Anyone please.. I need this...

Comment: And what does the error say? Trying to understand the code you are cobbling together usually goes a long way in creating a good solution.

Comment: And doesn't that indicate that your syntax is wrong? Look at your quotes. You need to escape quotes within a string.

Comment: Thats what I said, I am getting a syntax error... I have tried a lot of stuff...

Comment: seem exactly like my problem.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17070635/check-if-email-already-exists-in-database-jquery-php

hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You're using double quotes incorrectly.

```
returnValue = "<img src=\"Images1/n.png\"><font color=\"#cc0000\"><b>'" + args + "'</b> is    already in use.</font>";
```

It's really bad habit to generate HTML or any markup like this. Consider changing it to templating system in the client side or find more elegant solution in the back-end.

Comment: Ok, the error is gone, but the bigger question now is: Why doesnt this execute?? I have absolutely nothing happening here!!! its not even  entering the method!...??

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be trying to call the stored procedure that your C# code uses to check if an email is available from your client-side Ajax call.  You should be calling the method you have defined instead.