# check if email already exists in database jquery +php

Tags: php, jquery, database, email

Hy I'm trying to validate the email address in  a registration form. I want to check if the address exists in the database;

i have the following function:

```
function validateEmailRepeat(){
        // check if email exists in the database;
             var emailVal = $('#email').val();
             // assuming this is a input text field

            $.post('check_email.php', {'email' : emailVal}, function(data) {
                    if(data==1) 
                        {
                        email.addClass("error");
                        emailInfo.text("Adress exists");
                        emailInfo.addClass("error");
                        dataExist=1;
                            }

                    else {

                        email.removeClass("error");
                        emailInfo.text("Valid adress");
                        emailInfo.removeClass("error");
                        dataExist=0;
                            }
                        });

                        if(dataExist==1)
                         return false;
                         else
                         return true;

                    }
```

the check_email.php looks like this:

```
require_once('db.php');

if (isset($_POST['email'])){
$email=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['email']);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE `username`='".$email."'";
$select=mysqli_query($con,$sql) or die("fail");
$row = mysqli_num_rows($select);

if ($row >0) {

    echo 1;
}else echo 0 ;

}
else
echo "post error";
```

i'm new at this . So don't be to tough. thanks in advance.

LE:Sorry ! i forgot the question...
the problem is that my function returns true if I define var dataExist outside of the function form $.post
and if i let it like it is now in the function I  get "dataExist is not defined " error and returns true

Le: the PHP returns the expected 1 and 0 just the way i wanted..

LE:
seems like defining the

var dataExist=0;

outside the function `validateEmailRepeat()` resolved the issue.

if there's another way more elegant please tell me because this seems a little stupid to me.

Comment: You've told us what you're doing but what's the question here?

Comment: Be aware of that: johndoe@gmail.com, john.doe@gmail.com, John.Doe@gmail.com, j.o.h.n.d.o.e@gmail.com, etc..  All are the same email

Comment: You forgot to actually ask a question.  Is there some observable problem with the code you've written?  Is it not behaving as expected?  Is there an error?  In what way are you looking for help?

Comment: +1 for simply using `mysqli`. You're still open to SQL injection and should look into ***prepared statements***, but by using `mysqli` you're doing better than 90% of the other questions I look at on this site. Keep it up and look into using ***prepared statements***.

Comment: thanks! I sure will soon!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you cannot return the value into the called function, because ajax work asynchronously.

```
                function validateEmailRepeat(){
                // check if email exists in the database;
                     var emailVal = $('#email').val();
                // assuming this is a input text field

                $.post('check_email.php', {'email' : emailVal}, function(data) {
                    if(data==1){
                        email.addClass("error");
                        emailInfo.text("Adress exists");
                        emailInfo.addClass("error");
                        dataExist=1;
                    }else{
                        email.removeClass("error");
                        emailInfo.text("Valid adress");
                        emailInfo.removeClass("error");
                        dataExist=0;
                    }
                        $('#some_input').val(dataExist);
                        validateUserName();
                    });
                }

                function validateUserName() {
                    var input =  $('#some_input').val();
                    if (input) {
                       alert("This username is already taken");// whatever
                    } else {
                         // whatever
                    }

                };
```

Comment: and this is better than what i've done why? it surely looks better, but why it's better than declaring variable dataExist globally?

Comment: The problem is: you can't get the value of dataExist outside the ajax request, for that reason is the callback function "validateUserName();" and now I change for this: ValidateUserName(dataExist); in the callback and the function as follow: function ValidateUserName(xxx){if (xxx){alert('already taken')}else{//whatever}}   sorry my english man...good luck

Comment: thanks for your help and your time to explain . I got the point

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing the username with the email address. Is this how your DB works?

> $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE `username`='".$email."'";

I bet you have a field in your database for the email itself, otherwise i suggest you do this. The query should look like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '".$email."'";
```

Without the single quotes for the column.

Comment: the php code works just fine . in the database username=email..the problem is with the function. i cant get it to return false when the email is found in the database